# Java calculator that you give a string like 123*123 and gives you the answer

Tags: java, calculator

I am trying to make a calculator in java. At the moment, it only works using strings that contain spaces, like so: `"123 * 123"`.

I would like to make it split the string when it doesn't have spaces, like so: `"123*123"`.

How can I do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     System.out.println("Porfavor insira a sua conta: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numeroEsquerda = scanner.nextInt();
        String op = scanner.next();
        int numeroDireita = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(conta(numeroEsquerda,op,numeroDireita));
    }

    private static int conta(int numeroEsquerda, String op, int numeroDireita) {
        switch (op.charAt(0)) {
        case '+':
            return numeroEsquerda + numeroDireita;
        case '-':
            return numeroEsquerda - numeroDireita;
        case '*':
            return numeroEsquerda * numeroDireita;
        case '/':
            return numeroEsquerda / numeroDireita;
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown operator:" + op);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you need to write a parser which doesn't need spaces.

Comment: the question is how can i keep like the same thing but without having to do for example 1 + 2, how can i make it 1+2

Comment: like you give a string 1234*1234 and gives you the answer

Comment: @MiguelFerreira You'll have to parse the String differently. Either you read 1 character after another using `Scanner` or you parse the input String yourself (loops & `.charAt(...)`)

Comment: I don't really know if i understand what you mean im farly new to java and programming :\

Comment: @MiguelFerreira What's the problem in your code ?

Comment: you'll not be able to give `1234*1234` as your input as the scanner will try to parse an integer but fails since it reads `1234*1234` as a string, thus, failing at the very start. You'll have to do as what ParkerHalo suggested or take a look into regular expressions and `string.split()` to extract the 2 numbers from the operators.

Comment: ye thanks man i think i know it now

Comment: How can i divide the string into 2 and use the if to detect +,-,*,/

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to split the string:

```
s = "123*321";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(.)(\\d+)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.matches()) {
    String numeroEsquerda = m.group(1);
    String op = m.group(2);
    String numeroDireita = m.group(3);
} else {
    new RuntimeException("Invalid input");
}
```

Note that you still need to convert the number strings to ints.

Comment: Mind that your indexes were wrong. `m.group(0)` is the whole pattern, not just the first matching group.

Comment: @Tom Doh! Thank you for fixing.